# Contract call does not works through web3

Tags: web3js, transactions, truffle-contract

I have contract method `transferFrom` that failed when I calling it the site's from backend, but in the same time it works from Remix.

Both calls are performed through Metamask. Initially I thought that it could be related to gas amount but when I called method from Remix and specified gas amount that was used for failed transaction - it works, so I  have no idea what is the problem.

Here is [failed transaction](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0x091dbed470dd049def7748f879d4c0c2e2780c54b08904fe61f397401f965ae9) that called using this code:

```
Eth.contract._approve(toAddress, fromAddress, amount)
.then(async result => {
  const tx = await Eth.contract.transferFrom.sendTransaction(fromAddress, toAddress, amount);

  return res.json({success: true, data: {from: fromAddress, to: toAddress, amount: amount, tx: tx}});
})
.catch(error => {
  return res.boom.badImplementation('Unable to approve transfer ' + amount + ' tokens to the address ' + fromAddress, {success: false});
});
```

`_approve` is special function in the contract that accessible only for contract owner and has 3 parameters insteand of 2 required by ERC20 interface.

And here is [working transaction](https://rinkeby.etherscan.io/tx/0xe4e6d67eedfd6c72b4ed0f1d8bb9a21e3fae3726c3f320475dea7a175aed4a29) that is called from Remix with the same contract loaded.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally I got it. Issue is unrelated to the contract code except couple of `require` statements inside it.

Methods `transferFrom` relies on internal `approved` member that contains alloed amount to transfer between 2 accounts. It was done to merge duplicated functionality of methods `transfer` and `transferFrom` (see ERC20 Token interface). But it was mistake.

On the site's backend called consequently 2 methods using `await`:

- approve
- transferFrom

But when `approve` was already awaited and response received it wasn't actually mined by the network and `approved` mapping does not contains required amount. Thus statement `require(approved[_from][_to] >= _amount)` failed.

Solution: do not merge logically unmergeble.

Answer (score 1):

Using `transferFrom` involves three accounts:

- owner: Account who has the tokens
- recipient: Account that will receive tokens
- sender: Account making the transaction

Now the sequence should be

1. the owner has to approve the sender

   ```
   token.approve(sender, amount, { from: owner });
   ```
2. The sender can make the transfer

   ```
   token.transferFrom(owner, recipient, amount, { from: sender });
   ```

Comment: This is exactly what I did, just omitted approve step. Approved correct amount, as I mentioned this call works when performed through Remix.

Comment: @AlexG.P. In your code it doesn't have the transaction options ie the last parameter `{ from: sender }`, without that you are sending the transaction from the default account.

Comment: it does not works. By default I have only one wallet/address as all transactions sender - it is contract owner/creator. I updated post with full approve-transfer code. Approve and transfer performed by contract creator, so it is the same as you specified. And it does not helps.

Comment: Moreover, as you can see the same transaction with the same transaction initiator works perfectly from remix.

Comment: Both transactions are identical, in geth vm trace they have a similar start, make two external calls, the failed tx makes a revert around step 1050 but the successful keep going until step 2190. Without the contract code is impossible to say anything more.